# How do I configure WWW::Mechanize to work through a proxy?

Tags: perl, proxy, www-mechanize

I sit behind a proxy and have HTTP and WWW::Mechanize working OK locally.

But advice || pointers as to how to get through a proxy please.

Regards
Ian

Answer (score 8):

[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW::Mechanize) is an extension of [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::UserAgent):

> `WWW::Mechanize` is a proper subclass of
>   `LWP::UserAgent` and you can also use
>   any of `LWP::UserAgent`'s methods.

So you can just use `->env_proxy`, or `->proxy` — as described in [the manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP::UserAgent#Proxy_attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Excellent clue depesz||cjm.

It was actually a matter of "rtfm".
Forgot the need for the environment variable "HTTP_PROXY".
Do not get old you guys !!

Ian